# JQuery Vs. C#: Using a master textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a list of 100+ textboxes on my page. I want to have one textbox at the top that can change all of them to its value, yet still have the others able to be independent (as in, using one variable for all wouldn't work). They should be able to be changed individually, with the master one sort of acting as a "Change All".

My question is, would this work better by looping through and doing a postback in c#? Or can I dynamically change them all in jquery? Which would you recommend?

Comment: What will be the behaviour if the user has changed 4 of the textboxes and then types in the top one? Will all the textboxes on the page be reset to the value of the first textbox?

Comment: I would say JQuery is the way to go. Use the `Change` event in JQuery on the master textbox, and use a selector to set the value of all the other textboxes to the new value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would highly recommend changing them all with jquery. It could be as simple as something like this:

```
$('#txt_Master').change(function() {
    $('.childTextBoxes').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery would be the best option.. As there is too much of load using the server side controls..

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvt8J/)

```
<input type="text" class="master"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>
<input type="text" class="child"/>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.master').on('change', function() {

       $('.child').val(  $(this).val() );
    });
});​
```